# How to dynamically ignore property when I'm Serialization object to json using TJson.ObjectToJsonString

Tags: json, delphi, serialization

I have this class:

```
unit untPerson;
interface
type TPerson = class
  private
    fName  : string;
    fEmail : string;
    fAge   : integer;
  published 
    property Name  : string  read fName  write fName;
    property Email : string  read fEmail write fEmail;
    property Age   : integer read fAge   write fAge;
end;
implementation
end.
```

And i need to serialize to Json using this code

```
TJson.ObjectToJsonString(objPerson, []);
```

But i need to skip Age if equal 0.

```
if objPerson.Age = 0 then
  result := '{"name":"Lucas", "email":"lucas@github.com"}'
else
  result := '{"name":"Lucas", "email":"lucas@github.com", "age":30}';
```

How Can I Do?

```
if objPerson.Age = 0 then
  result := '{"name":"Lucas", "email":"lucas@github.com"}'
else
  result := '{"name":"Lucas", "email":"lucas@github.com", "age":30}';
```

Comment: I'm nut sure if this also works when serializing objects to JSON but when Delphi is saving values of component properties it is also checking to see if value of the specific property differs from [Default Property Value](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Default_Property_Values). If it differs the property value is stored in DFM but if it has the same value the specific property isn't stored in DFM at all. I'm guessing that Delphi JSON serialization might use similar approach. So try declaring default value for your `Age` property and see if it still gets written into JSON

Comment: AFAICS, `TJson` does not have that capability. It does have an option to ignore empty strings, but not integers. And there is no syntax for specifying default values. But you might be able to implement something manually by declaring a custom JSON attribute derived from `JSonReflectAttribute` and `TJSONInterceptor` ([see this](https://en.delphipraxis.net/topic/6155-tjson-suppressemptyvalues-for-empty-integer-double-and-class-fields/) for a starting point). But there are tons of 3rd party JSON serializers for Delphi, I'm sure some of them have what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can't dynamically ignore properties by using code: `TJson.ObjectToJsonString(objPerson, []);`.
You can put empty string by custom `TJSONInterceptor`, like  Remy Lebeau says in comments(https://en.delphipraxis.net/topic/6155-tjson-suppressemptyvalues-for-empty-integer-double-and-class-fields/), but to exclude it from json you need to put option `joIgnoreEmptyStrings`: `TJson.ObjectToJsonString(objPerson, [joIgnoreEmptyStrings]);`.

One more way to do it: use custom converter (descendant of `TJsonConverter`), but problem is that you can’t use `TJson.ObjectToJsonString` in this case, because it have precompiled code with creating `JSONMarshal` using specifically `TJSONConverter` class without possibility of overriding: `TJSONMarshal.Create(TJSONConverter.Create, true, CFRegConverters)`;. So you need to reimplement all chain of call `TJSON.ObjectToJsonString -> ObjectToJsonValue -> TJSONConverters.GetJSONMarshaler -> TJSONMarshal.Create(TJSONConverter.Create, true, CFRegConverters)`;. And after that you must use this custom implementation.

Easiest way – to add custom method directly to class:

```
  TPerson = class
  private
    fName  : string;
    fEmail : string;
    fAge   : integer;
  published
    function ToJsonString : string; virtual;
    class function FromJsonString(const AJsonStr : string) : TPerson;
    property Name  : string  read fName  write fName;
    property Email : string  read fEmail write fEmail;
    property Age   : integer read fAge   write fAge;
    end;
```

In this case – you can use any custom logic, but the same code: `TJson.ObjectToJsonString(objPerson, [])`;.will does not work correctly. You must use these new methods.

And last – you can try to find some other 3rd party JSON serializers.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative solution, [mORMot](https://synopse.info/files/html/Synopse%20mORMot%20Framework%20SAD%201.18.html) have this diamond, and you can always use ObjectToJson to serialize very fast any TObject in a centralized way:

```
program TestJson;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  Syncommons, mORMot;

type TPerson = class
  private
    fName  : string;
    fEmail : string;
    fAge   : integer;
  public
    class procedure ClassWriter(const aSerializer: TJSONSerializer;
                                aValue: TObject; aOptions: TTextWriterWriteObjectOptions);
  published
    property Name  : string  read fName  write fName;
    property Email : string  read fEmail write fEmail;
    property Age   : integer read fAge   write fAge;
end;

{ TPerson }

class procedure TPerson.ClassWriter(const aSerializer: TJSONSerializer;
                                    aValue: TObject; aOptions: TTextWriterWriteObjectOptions);
var Person: TPerson absolute aValue;
begin
  if Person.Age=0 then
    aSerializer.AddJSONEscape(['Name',Person.Name,
                               'Email',Person.Email
                              ])
  else
    aSerializer.AddJSONEscape(['Name',Person.Name,
                               'Email',Person.Email,
                               'Age',Person.Age
                              ]);
end;

var Person : TPerson;
begin
  TJSONSerializer.RegisterCustomSerializer(TPerson,nil,TPerson.ClassWriter);
  Person := TPerson.Create;
  try
    Person.Name := 'Jon';
    Person.Email := 'jon@gmail.com';
    Person.Age := 10;
    writeln(ObjectToJson(Person)); // Result {"Name":"Jon","Email":"jon@gmail.com","Age":10}

    Person.Age := 0;
    writeln(ObjectToJson(Person)); // Result {"Name":"Jon","Email":"jon@gmail.com"}
  finally
    Person.Free;
  end;
  readln;
end.
```

Please, find further details in the [amazing documentation](https://synopse.info/files/html/Synopse%20mORMot%20Framework%20SAD%201.18.html#TITL_52)